# Getting a 403 - permission denied when using aws client to set the acl to public-read

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage

I am attempting to change the asl of a file (100KB.file) I have within IBM COS: bucket: 'devtest1.ctl-internal.nasv.cos' and am receiving the following message:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObjectAcl
>   operation: Access Denied

It seems like my AWS credentials (or call) do not have the correct permissions to allow the ACL update.

Command:

> aws --endpoint-url=https://s3.us-south.objectstorage.softlayer.net
>   s3api put-object-acl --bucket devtest1.ctl-internal.nasv.cos --key
>   100KB.file --acl public-read

Return:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObjectAcl
>   operation: Access Denied

Answer (score 0):

You haven’t mentioned that you have configured hmac credentials on your bucket, so I’ll assume you haven't.  I'm also assuming that operations other than `PutObjectAcl` do not work for you.

Try adding hmac credentials:

[image]

Then ...

[image]

Source: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/hmac/credentials.html#using-hmac-credentials

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue as well using the AWS CLI. However, you can do the same operation using cURL and providing your IBM Cloud IAM token.

```
curl -X "PUT" "https://{endpoint}/{bucket-name}/{object-name}?acl" \
 -H "x-amz-acl: public-read" \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer {token}" \
 -H "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" \
```